# Access Violation reading linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Hi all i've encounter a small error in this function but i cant figure it out what went wrong with this and i get access violation reading location. I have implemented a somewhat function that uses this method too but it is working. Can i know why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

this is my int main() code:

```
typedef struct node{
int item;
struct node *next;
} ListNode;

void spilt(ListNode *head, ListNode **ptrEvenList, ListNode **ptrOddList);
int main()
{
int i = 0, j = 0;
ListNode *head = NULL, *temp = NULL, *even = NULL, *odd = NULL;

printf("Enter a value:");
scanf("%d", &i);
while (i != -1)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        temp = head;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        temp = temp->next;

    }
    temp->item = i;
    printf("Enter a value:");
    scanf("%d", &i);
}

spilt(head, even, odd);




    getch();
    return 0;


}



void spilt(ListNode *head, ListNode **ptrEvenList, ListNode **ptrOddList)
{
int i = 0;
ListNode *even=NULL, *odd=NULL,*temp1=NULL,*temp2=NULL;
ListNode *test = head;

odd = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
even = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
temp1 = even;
temp2 = odd;


while (test != NULL)
{


    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        temp1->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp1->item = head->item;

    }

    else if (i%2==1)
    {
        temp2->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        temp2 = temp2->next;
        temp2->item = head->item;
    }

    test = test->next; // error (access violation reading location)
    i++;



}

}
```

Working function below:

```
int search(ListNode *head, int value)
{
int i = 0;
ListNode *node = head;
if (head == NULL)
    return -1;

while (node != NULL)
{

    if (node->item == value)
        return i;
    node = node->next;
    i++;
}
```

}

Comment: I really can't find an issue with this. The error must be occurring because you try to access next pointer when test itself is NULL. Could you confirm if this is happening.

Comment: i did a print out of test and it is not NULL. but when the error is shown, it says 'test 0xcdcdcdcd {item=??? next=??? } node *'

Comment: i've included my int main code above too thanks for hellping out

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely not null initially since it is entering that while loop. However, at the time of the error it becomes NULL. Is i =0 when the error occurs?

Comment: when it occurs it is not at i=0. ok i get it. the thing is trying to access the data when test is null. but the initial while condition should be to stop the loop when it reaches the last item of the linked list but can i know why it is still looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int item;
    struct node *next;
} ListNode;

void spilt(ListNode *head, ListNode **ptrEvenList, ListNode **ptrOddList);

void print(ListNode *np){
    while(np){
        printf("%d ", np->item);
        np = np->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    ListNode *head = NULL, *temp = NULL, *even = NULL, *odd = NULL;

    printf("Enter a value:");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    while (i != -1){
        if (head == NULL){
            head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = head;
        } else {
            temp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->item = i;
        temp->next = NULL;
        printf("Enter a value:");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }
    printf("head:");print(head);
    spilt(head, &even, &odd);
    printf("even:");print(even);
    printf("odd:");print(odd);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void spilt(ListNode *head, ListNode **ptrEvenList, ListNode **ptrOddList){
    int i = 0;
    ListNode *even=NULL, *odd=NULL, *temp1=NULL, *temp2=NULL;
    ListNode *test = head;

    while (test != NULL){
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            if (even == NULL){
                even = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                temp1 = even;
            } else {
                temp1->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
            temp1->item = test->item;
            temp1->next = NULL;
        } else {//if (i%2==1)
            if (odd == NULL){
                odd = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                temp2 = odd;
            } else {
                temp2->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }
            temp2->item = test->item;
            temp2->next = NULL;
        }
        test = test->next;
        ++i;
    }
    *ptrEvenList = even;
    *ptrOddList = odd;,
}
```